# How do I display first item in Json in vue js table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to put some data in a html table. But when I attempt it I get the header row duplicating itself multiple times.

**Data:**

```
export const rates = [
  {
    lvrLow: 0.8,
    loanRanges: [
      {
        loanLow: 0,
        loanHigh: 300000.0,
      },
      {
        loanLow: 300000.01,
        loanHigh: 500000.0,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    lvrLow: 0.95,
    loanRanges: [
      {
        loanLow: 0,
        loanHigh: 300000.0,
      },
      {
        loanLow: 300000.01,
        loanHigh: 500000.0,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**Vuejs Table row:**

```
 <tr v-for="item in rates" :key="item.id">
        <th>Low LVR</th>
        <th>High LVR</th>
        <th
          class="text-start"
          v-for="range in item.loanRanges"
          :key="range.id"
          colspan="1"
        >
          {{ range.loanLow }}
        </th>
        <th
          class="text-start"
          v-for="range in item.loanRanges"
          :key="range.id"
          colspan="1"
        >
          {{ range.loanHigh }}
        </th>
      </tr>
```

**This is the layout I'm trying to achieve:**

```
      <tr>
            <th>Low LVR</th>
            <th>High LVR</th>
            <th>
                0
            </th>
            <th>
                 300000.00
            </th>
  <th>
                 300000.01
            </th>

             <th>
                500000.00
            </th>
          </tr>
```

But with the vuejs I have above, I get the same row duplicating itself multiple times.

[image]

How do I adjust this so it only shows the first loan Range as the header of the table?

It should display as follows:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Do you want the loanLow and loanHigh in the same row as LowLVR and HighLVR or in a new row?

Comment: Hi @YashMaheshwari in the same row. "Low LVR" and "High LVR" are just headings.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the result? Also does `id` exist in your JSON? You are using `:key="item.id"` but `id` is not in your JSON structure.

Comment: HI @Chin.Udara, I've updated the question with a screenshot of the current output. I don't currently have id in my json.

Comment: [this](https://jsfiddle.net/36xjy5qm/) is your code in a Fiddle. It is working fine. There must be something else wrong in your component code or logic.

Comment: the code does run fine. But as you can see in Fiddle it has multiple rows. I want the first one only.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the JSON structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are iterating over the `rates` array, which contain multiple objects hence it will create one row for each object, and as the `loanRanges` values are the same in all the objects, hence it appears to be duplicating.

Here in the below code, I have updated the `loanRanges` value for the second object and it works fine.

Edit:
As you only want a single row to be displayed, remove the for loop from the `tr` and apply the for loop only on the `td` iterating over the `loanRanges` ojbect.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      rates: [
      {
        lvrLow: 0.8,
        loanRanges: [
          {
            loanLow: 0,
            loanHigh: 300000.0
          },
          {
            loanLow: 300000.01,
            loanHigh: 500000.0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        lvrLow: 0.95,
        loanRanges: [
          {
            loanLow: 0,
            loanHigh: 300000.0
          },
          {
            loanLow: 300000.01,
            loanHigh: 500000.0
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Low LVR</th>
      <th>High LVR</th>
      <th
        class="text-start"
        v-for="(range, i) in rates[0].loanRanges"
        :key="i"
        colspan="1"
      >
        {{ range['loanLow'] }}
      </th>
      <th
        class="text-start"
        v-for="(range, i) in rates[0].loanRanges"
        :key="i"
        colspan="1"
      >
        {{ range['loanHigh'] }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Edit:

Using computed property to create the table headers.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th v-for="(header, index) in headers" :key="index"> {{ header }}</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
data () {
    return {
        tableHeader: ['Low LVR', 'High LVR'],
      rates: [
      {
        lvrLow: 0.8,
        loanRanges: [
          {
            loanLow: 0,
            loanHigh: 300000.0
          },
          {
            loanLow: 300000.01,
            loanHigh: 500000.0
          },
          {
            loanLow: 500000.01,
            loanHigh: 1000000.0
          },
           {
            loanLow: 1000000.01,
            loanHigh: 2000000.0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        lvrLow: 0.95,
        loanRanges: [
          {
            loanLow: 0,
            loanHigh: 300000.0
          },
          {
            loanLow: 300000.01,
            loanHigh: 500000.0
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    headers () {
        this.rates[0].loanRanges.map((range) => {
        this.tableHeader.push(range.loanLow)
        this.tableHeader.push(range.loanHigh)
      })
        return this.tableHeader
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to iterate all of them. I just want to display the header as one line. I don't want multiple lines. Please see screenshots above.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari thats exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated!

Comment: @YashMaheshwari The second `th` should iterate over `rates[1].loanRanges`. Not `[0]` I think.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari there is one problem with this. If there are more rates. Say another 2-3. Then it doesn't order them properly. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/56pf0bhu/

Comment: @deanjmay, The way you want to arrange is possible either by displaying the low and high in the same th like ` {{ range['loanLow'] }} {{ range['loanHigh'] }}` or you can use a computed property to create a header array and then use that to display the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Low LVR and High LVR header are inside the loop for rates array
you should make the code like this:

```
 <tr>
    <th>Low LVR</th>
    <th>High LVR</th>
 </tr>
 <tr v-for="item in rates" :key="item.id">
    <td
      class="text-start"
      v-for="range in item.loanRanges"
      :key="range.id"
      colspan="1"
    >
      {{ range.loanLow }}
    </td>
    <td
      class="text-start"
      v-for="range in item.loanRanges"
      :key="range.id"
      colspan="1"
    >
      {{ range.loanHigh }}
    </td>
  </tr>
```

so your header will not be inside as rates iterates.

as for layout that you want to acheive:

```
      <tr>
        <th>Low LVR</th>
        <th>High LVR</th>
        <th>
            0
        </th>
        <th>
             300000.00
        </th>
        <th>
             300000.01
        </th>

         <th>
            500000.00
        </th>
      </tr>
```

it will display one line header.

Comment: This will give two rows for one header!

Comment: I need them to be on the same row.